# Pointer to a function that takes pointer parameters

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I am trying to create a function pointer that takes in a pointer to double as an argument. What is the proper syntax to write in `main`?

This is what I have but it keeps spitting out errors.

```
void (*ptr)(double, double, (*double), (*double) );
```

Answer (score 8):

It is the same way you would declare a `double *` parameter in a function's parameter list:

```
void (* ptr) (double, double, double *, double *);
```

Can be assigned to a function like:

```
void something (double w, double x, double *py, double *pz) {
}
```

---

This is true in the general case, no matter how complicated it gets. For example, a pointer to a function that takes an `int` and another function pointer (which points to a function that takes a `double` and a `void *` and returns a `char*`) as a parameter:

```
void (* ptr) (int, char * (*) (double, void *));
```

Then:

```
char * g (double w, void *) {
    ...
}

void f (int x, char * (* y) (double, void *)) { 
    ...
}

// usage, elsewhere:
ptr = &f;
ptr(0, &g);
```

Comment: By the way, sometimes I find it helpful to `typedef` types to something syntactically simpler. Then I can clearly see what's going on, and substitute the original types back in. For example, `typedef double * double_ptr` makes `void (* ptr) (double, double, double_ptr, double_ptr)` clear, then substituting `double *` back in shows you the correct syntax.